# Xcode iOS Base SDK Missing

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, target

I have an old iOS app that I never distributed and am now trying to work on the project again.  It worked fine with an earlier version of Xcode but I was not ready to deploy it at that time.  Now I am using the current version of Xcode but I have an error that there is a missing base SDK.  I have explored every posting here with that error message and they did not work for me.

On investigation in Xcode.  I can choose my app under "Project" pane.  With the Info tab chosen, it has under Deployment Target as "Mac OS X Deployment Target" and Default in the drop list.

This is an iOS app and not a Mac OS X app.  How do I change this?

I already have the base SDK as the Latest iOS.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open Xcode and Press cmd + 1
2. In left panel choose your project -> Your target in center panel-> Build Settings in right panel
3. Find "Base SDK" and choose "Latest iOS". If you see a Release and Debug lines, then choose this for both Release and Debug.
4. Restart your Xcode

Comment: Restart XCode? Why?!? It worked, I'm just saying why the hell... just wasted 20 mins by not even suspecting that a restart would be required.

Comment: New XCode version is not require a restarting, but in some case it's helpful

Answer (score -1):

Usually when you see this, it's when you've got an old iOS project and you're using a version of Xcode that uses a newer base iOS. In those cases, you can click on the target on the top of the tree structure of the Project Navigator on the left, and you'll see the project settings. There's a button labelled "Validate Settings" and will show up near the lower center portion of the main panel. Click on it.

If that doesn't do it (e.g. it's from a *really* old version and Xcode can't figure out how to remedy it), it might be easier to recreate the project. Create a new iOS project and then copy your source code, its NIBs and resources into that project. Maybe that will be easier than trying to fix the old project you have.